# PyQt5 changing width of vertical scrollbar in stylesheet changes minimumSizeHint, want to avoid that

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyqt, pyqt5

I'm making a widget, where i want to have the smallest height. I can achieve that, but when i change the stylesheet, the minimumSzeHint gets lower. This is the result:

[image]

Leftmost box is how it turns out. Middle is how it behaves, except that i don't set a stylesheet. The Right image is what i want. I can achieve that by removing width for a QScrollbar::vertical.

```
 QScrollBar:vertical {
    border: none;
    background-color: rgba(255,255,255,0);
    width: 10px; ##<---- Remove this, to "fix"##
    margin: 0px 0px 0px 0px;
}
```

How can i keep this change, or work around it. I need this change for something else, so just removing it isn't as ideal as it may seem from this image.

I made this with using a custom QTreeWidget having QTreeWidgetItems, adding that to a QVBoxLayout, which a use as layout for a QWidget. 4 QTreeWidgets are made.

I then setStyleSheet and i  resize the widget to save space with:

```
self.resize(self.sizeHint().width(),self.minimumHeight())
```

self here points to the QWidget itself. Can post simplified code, but it doesn't do all that much in explaining this.

Answer (score 1):

I solved this for now, partially at least, by adding some margin to the scrollbar. The exact reason why this works, i don't know. But i think it's got something to do with how minimum size is calculated, along with the space the scrollbar takes, and how that somehow affects minimum size. So i guess i made up for the loss in width (by increasing width, i get the expected results.) by using the margin for width. See changes here:

```
QScrollBar:vertical {
    border: none;
    background-color: rgba(255,255,255,0);
    width: 10px;
    margin: 0px 0px 0px 5px;
 }
```